# Custom DateTime format for Oracle Database

Tags: c#, oracle, datetime

I'm currently reading `DateTime` items from an Oracle database, which are in the format `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss`, but I need them to be stored as follows: `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`.

I've tried two approaches. The first I've tried splits a string version of the date into parts and reassembles it to give me the output I desire. However, converting this to a DateTime object reverts it to the original format. Here's the code:

```
public static DateTime FormatDateTimeForPDB(string dateTimeString)
{
    DateTime formattedDateTime;
    char[] illegals = { '/', ' ', ':' };

    string[] array = dateTimeString.Split(illegals);
    string date = array[2] + "-" + array[1] + "-" + array[0] + " " + array[3] + ":" + array[4] + ":" + array[5];

    formattedDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(date);      
    return formattedDateTime;
}
```

A breakpoint at `Convert.ToDateTime(date)` shows date as **2012-09-07 15:01:03** which is the format I want, but as a string, not a DateTime.

I've also tried using the DateTimeFormatInfo attribute as discussed by the user *tatis* over [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/csharplanguage/thread/af4f5a1e-f81d-47fe-981d-818e785b8847), but all that managed to do was swap the month and day fields (giving me `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss`). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are confusing how the SQL tools are displaying the stored information to you with how it is stored. It does not have a "format" inside the database.

Comment: If the Date is not stored as a date, fire the guy who did the DB schema.

Comment: @SteveB I don't have that kind of authority. Oded, Although that's true, C# does require a format. The format it gets back is not valid.

Comment: Parse the date using a format string, do not try to split/parse it by yourself...

Comment: The `DateTime` structure does not store `DateTime` in any sort of format either. When you see uses the _default_ format string for your computer.

Comment: I see. A code revision may be needed. Thanks, Oded.

Comment: Can you explain what the end result for this is? Why do you want to do this? Perhaps we can offer a better option.

Comment: I'm basically storing a time for an object which informs of the last time the object was accessed, and then updating this time every time it is accessed.

Comment: @Skulmuk - So why do you need to mess around with formats? Even if the data is stored as a string in the database (shouldn't be, by the way), you can ensure a consistent format using format strings.

Comment: I dont have control over the DB, unfortunately. I've bypassed my issue by merely converting the incoming time using the function I posted and passing that into the check instead.

Comment: @Oded the DateTime structure does store the DateTime in a format: binary twos complement integer format.

Comment: @phoog - Nit picker. You know I meant a string representation.

Comment: @Oded yes, indeed.  I got very little sleep last night, which seems to have made me somewhat pedantic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are worried about parsing the date string into a DateTime in C# take a look at DateTime's ParseExact method.  Documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx).

Something like this:

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
String format = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss";
return DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
```